# Is an <a> tag always phrasing content?

Tags: html, specifications

There are currently two (or more??) specifications dealing with the `<a>` tag in HTML. I'm curious which is the one currently implemented in browsers, or "correct", as far as something can be "correct" in an evolving ecosystem.

- [HTML5 Working Draft ("a" element)](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element) lists the `<a>` tag as phrasing content when the tag only contains phrasing content.
- [W3C Recommendation ("a" element)](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element) lists the `<a>` tag as always phrasing content.

The latter seems to be more up to date, but the former sounds more correct to me.

Comment: There are two specifications dealing with the a element: W3C HTML5, and WHATWG HTML. Not one specific 2011 WD and the W3C REC. There are *numerous* WDs of HTML5 in 2011 alone, and it has seen numerous significant changes over the course of a decade, and there are more than two different versions of the a element definition in W3C HTML5 alone.

Comment: Having said that, I'm not sure if browsers actually distinguish between flow content and phrasing content, since either way their job mostly is to display them using CSS, and their content category only loosely correlates with their default CSS display type.

Comment: Sounds good, so as long as I pick a pretty recent spec (I'm considering going with https://www.w3.org/WebPlatform/docs/html51/ but would love suggestions) and stick to it, I'm going to be close enough.